# .Net Core 3.0 invoking .Net Framework 4.8 program via Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .net Core 3.0 application attempting to invoke .Net Framework 4.8 via reflection. Our goal is to read encrypted AppSettings.config (xml) with ConfigurationManager, which is not possible in .Net Core. Unencrypted yes, but encrypted (CipherData), no.

My reflection code that accesses a static class & method goes like this:

```
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(exeFullName);
        MethodInfo method = assembly.GetType(nameSpacenClass).GetMethod(methodName);
        if (method != null)
        {
            object rtnVal = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { jsonParms });
            return rtnVal;
        }
        else
            return null;
```

The method.Invoke errorred out with this exception message: 
FileNotFoundException: **Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'**. The system cannot find the file specified.

So I wrote a proxy program in .Net Framework 4.8, and use the same code to access the code that reads encrypted config via reflection, and it works fine.

Then, I coded .net Core 3.0 to access that proxy via reflection, and it fails. The proxy .Net Framework 4.8 has no references whatsoever. It is barebone. Yet core still requires ConfigurationManager even though the proxy does not. The Config program has only one reference - to System.Configuration.

Core 3.0 => Encrypted App.config => Failed

Core 3.0 => ConfigProgram 4.8 => App.Config => Failed

ConfigProgram 4.8 => App.config => **Works**

Proxy 4.8 => ConfigProgram 4.8 => App.Config => **Works**

Core 3.0 => Proxy 4.8 => ConfigProgram 4.8 => App.Config => Failed

I guess the referenced System.Configuration is not required for Reflection invoke by 4.8 but is required even though trough a barebone stepping stone, by .Net Core 3.0. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Out of interest, why not just develop in .NET Framework 4.8? And do you just need [CipherData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.cipherdata?view=netcore-2.0)? It seems to have been supported since .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: That would work, but then we are interested in using Core technology. Except that the encryption is a problem.

Comment: The rule of thumb is to use only .NET Core compatible dependencies (so .NET Framework assemblies are out of scope). What you tested above is the gray area, like "Reference .NET Framework libraries from .NET Standard" in [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-2-0/), so you are digging yourself a hole.

Answer (score 5):

When you load an assembly built for .NET Framework via reflection on .NET Core, it does not load any parts of .NET Framework - just your assembly ("user cod"). And some parts may or may not work. In your case it fails because the requested classes / assemblies of the code compiled for .NET Framework is not part of .NET Core.

This is the reason why only the cases where you start a .NET Framework application to begin with - thus booting up the .NET Framework Runtime - work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue with Cipher-Encrypted configuration file is now obsolete. With .NET Core 3.1 updates & .NET 6 and above, any application will be able to read Cipher-Encrypted Configuration files the same way they read unencrypted ones. For XML config files, we can read it this way:

```
    string assemblyName = Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType())?.GetName().Name;
    ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    configFile.ExeConfigFilename = Path.Combine(dir, $"{assemblyName}.dll.config");
    Configuration configCollection = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```